# why won't jquery datatable respond to click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a jquery datatable that populates from ajax but when I click on a row, the table click event handler does not fire.  Here is my datatable:

```
function initDataTables(watchlist) {
    $('#watchlistTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/MoneyMachine/getWatchlist.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {watchlist:watchlist}
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'Symbol' },
            { data: 'CompanyName' },
            { data: 'ClosePrice', class: 'text-right' },
            { data: 'PricePctChangeToday', class: 'text-right'},
            { data: 'CAGR', class: 'text-right'},
            { data: 'BenchmarkCAGR', class: 'text-right'},
            { data: 'DivYield', class: 'text-right'},
            { data: 'ExDivDate'},
            { data: 'AppreciationPotential', class: 'text-right'}
        ],    
        responsive: true,   //supposedly make table clickable but does nothing
        destroy: true       //A data table can only be initialized once.  It must be destroyed so it can be initialized again.      
    });
}
```

I've tried a couple different click events like this:

```
$('.dataTable').on( 'click', '.dataTable', function () {
    console.log("watchlistTable was clicked");
});
```

And like this:

```
$('#watchlistTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log("watchlistTable was clicked");
});
```

And like this:

```
$('.display').on( 'click', '.display', function () {
    console.log("watchlistTable was clicked");
});
```

But neither one fires.  Here is the html for it:

```
        <table id="watchlistTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sym</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Change%</th>
                <th>CAGR</th>
                <th>Benchmark<br>CAGR</th>
                <th>Div<br>Yield%</th>
                <th>Ex-Div<br>Date</th>
                <th>App<br>Pot%</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you aren't including a `<tbody>` in the original html

Try adding it to the target selector and delegating to the table itself instead

```
$('#watchlistTable').on( 'click', 'tbody tr', function () {...
```

---

Note that `$('.dataTable').on( 'click', '.dataTable', ...` is trying to delegate to an existing class `dataTable` and would only be triggered on other elements with that class that are inside it. Since nothing in the html shown has that class it's not clear what that element would even be and I doubt you have nested elements with same class

Comment: I just added it but it made no difference.

Comment: Make sure it is wrapped in a ready event handler then `$(function(){ /* code here */})`

Comment: This is what is inside my $(document).ready(function()    var watchlist = new watchlistPage();  And in the included watchlist.js file there is 
initDataTables("All Stocks");  So I know it is being hit because the table populates correctly.

Comment: Worst case can delegate to document `$(document).on( 'click', '#watchlistTable tbody tr', function () {`

Comment: Note I added an extra space erroneously in `' tbody tr'` in answer. Lleading space should be removed

Comment: I saw that.  But I missed the exact syntax you were saying.  I put it in like you have and that worked.  Thank you very much!